# Umbraco Search Pagination not working when i got to the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, razor, umbraco

i have tried for Pagination in search Result the code is below

```
    @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
 <form action="/movesearchresult/" method="GET">
        <input type="text" class="searchfield" placeholder="" name="query">
        <button class="searchbtn btn btn-default btn-sm">Search</button>
    </form>

     @{
        var searchQuery = Request.QueryString["query"];

    } 

       @{
        //number of results
        var searchResults = Umbraco.Search(searchQuery);
        var resultsCount = Umbraco.Search(searchQuery).Count();

        //required results per page
        var pageSize = 5;

        //retrieve current page from query string
        int currentPage = 1;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["query"]))
        {
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["query"], out currentPage);
        }

        //number of pages
        int pageCount = 1;
        if (resultsCount > pageSize)
        {
            pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)resultsCount / pageSize);
        }


    }

    <div>
        Page @currentPage of @pageCount pages
    </div>
    <div class="searchresults move-repo">
    <ul>
        @*Iterate through the search results skipping the results showing on any previous pages, and taking enough results to fill the page*@
        @foreach (var result in searchResults.Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@result.Url">@result.Name</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    </div>

    <ul>
    @for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="/movesearchresult?page=@i">Page @i</a>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
```

the pagination looks like this on the first search [image].

but when i got to the next page by clicking pagination i got the error screen 
which is [image] can any one let me know what am i missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems in the code:

The following:

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["query"]))
    {
        int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["query"], out currentPage);
    }
```

Should be

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["page"]))
    {
        int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out currentPage);
    }
```

And your link to the next page should include the query:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
{
    <li>
        <a href="/movesearchresult?page=@i&query=@searchQuery">Page @i</a>
    </li>
}
```

Be aware that you'll filter the @searchQuery first to avoid xss attacks

Also I can recommend using a package called [ezsearch](https://github.com/umco/umbraco-ezsearch) when implementing searching in umbraco, it's simple and well built

Comment: also can you let me know how to take the content inside the result because i can get only @result.Name , how i can get the content for that search

Comment: hi but my home screen went to death yellow screen after i have implemented your suggestion , throwing error on home screen  var searchResults = Umbraco.Search(searchQuery); Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: hi i have fixed it :) thank you for your answer can you please help on how to get contents

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to do `Umbraco.TypedContent(result.Id)` to get the IPublishedContent object, from there you can read the content using `GetPropertyValue`